# HDFS vs Local throughput performance

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I'am building one `local disk cache` for remote hdfs, the system will cache files on the local disk when reading from hdfs. I think this will increase the throughput.

If the data is read from PageCache, it does improve a lot; However, if I clear PageCache, the performance of Disk IO is not stable under different test conditions.

To be specific, I tested Parquet files(100MB per file) via database. In the same dataset, when I `select * from table` (that is, scan all columns), I saw that local IO rate is five times higher than hdfs; But when `I select result from table` (that is, scan one column), I see that hdfs IO rate is twice as high as local.

In this test, all codes are the same, including the number of threads (generally speaking, the more files, the more threads), except for the file system interface

In fact, the specific test results are no longer important. An obvious conclusion is that local is not always better than hdfs.

I want to know under what conditions the performance of local or hdfs will be better for reading parquet

Comment: Hard to tell if you're asking about SparkSQL, Flink SQL, Hive (which execution engine?), Impala, Presto, Drill, etc... They all exhibit different query performance. But also, who said hdfs is faster than local disk? - https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html

Comment: 100 MB files are smaller than the default HDFS block size, so you're not utilizing distributed HDFS storage properly. Otherwise, assuming you had tens of thousands of 100MB files, you could not cache them all on one disk, so I think you'll need better benchmarks / stress tests

Comment: @OneCricketeer，I actually compare the io performance, So this result is independent of the db system

Comment: Yeah, I Know if the thread is much enough, the local is worse than hdfs, but my case is the local disk io-load not fully utilized. so I think the disk io shoudl better than hdfs, and in some test cases have proved it.

Comment: Unclear what you mean "db system" since hadoop isn't a database... Parquet files are columnar, so yes, scanning single columns will be much faster than all columns

Comment: I mean the result is independent of `SparkSQL, Flink SQL, Hive , Impala, Presto, Drill`, for I just watch the io-throughput.    Yeah, but single column: hdfs faster than local; all columns: local faster than hdfs, which is my confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason why the local disk cache is slower than the remote file system(hdfs). This is because the I/O load of my local disk in some SQL case is so exhausted that the performance deteriorates dramatically. I added more disk to retests, and the local disk cache becomes faster than the remote file system.